# What is the datetime format to be used in this conversion?

Tags: python-3.x

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 918+00:00
```

When I try to convert a datetime like: `2018-11-20 14:31:33.799661918+00:00`

```
v_time=[]
for i in range (1,len(db)+1):
    p = (datetime.strptime(db.Time[i], "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%Y- 
         %m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    v_time.append(p)
db.Time = v_time
```

Comment: Per https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior nanoseconds aren't supported, you'll have to add your own processing or look for a third party library.

Comment: Yes, pandas is one of those third party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you anyway only display in seconds precision later, you could either strip simply the nanoseconds and live with microseconds precision (the nanoseconds might be not meaningful anyway)

```
from datetime import datetime

time_0 = '2018-11-20 14:31:33.799661918+00:00'
time_0_cut = time_0[0:26]

print(datetime.strptime(time_0_cut,
                        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

gives

```
2018-11-20 14:31:33
```

or, if you have to keep the nanoseconds precision, use [`numpy.datetime`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html) which is able to convert `datetimes` down to attoseconds precision

```
import numpy as np
print(np.datetime_as_string(np.datetime64(time_0)))
print(np.datetime_as_string(np.datetime64(time_0), unit='s'))  # display in sec precision
```

gives

```
2018-11-20T14:31:33.799661918
2018-11-20T14:31:33
```